# Hide Material UI Grid item and let next Grid Item slide into its position

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a form where some Textfields need to be hidden.
But if i am trying to hide an Grid item inside a Grid container with display: none, the next grid item does not slide to the position of the first one. It just creates this whitespace.

How can i solve this problem?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-grid-items-1v7u3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide grid instead of input. Because if you hide only the input grid still occupy the place

```
  <Grid item md={4} style={{ display: "none" }} xs={12}>
          <TextField label="Firstname"  />
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide elements or components in MaterialUI, there is the **Hidden** Component that toggles the visibility of components based on breakpoints and hidden utilities

Take a look at this snippet

```
<Grid container>
  <Hidden mdUp>
    <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
      <TextField label="Firstname"/>
   </Grid>
  </Hidden>
</Grid>
```

It's intuitive, from the 'md' breakpoint and above that grid item will be hidden. Check out the documentation [Hidden MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/).

Comment: For any block of code or component you want to hide, you'll just have to wrap it in the Hidden Component

Answer (score 0):

For hide Grid use component as **Box**

**component={ Box }**

import { Box, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

```
 <Grid item lg={ 2 } sm={ 2 }
                    sx={ {
                      backgroundColor: "yellow",
                      display:{xs:'none', sm:'block',lg:'block'}
                    } }
                    component={ Box }
                     
                  >Hide on xs Screen </Grid>
```